# How to rename only sub-folders without changing parent folder names

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder containing several hundred sub-folders in the format `Name, ID`. Each of these folders contain several sub folders, some of which contain spaces in their names. I would like to rename only the sub folders and not the parent folders by replacing the spaces with underscores, e.g. `C:\Location\John, 1234\My Documents` to `C:\Location\John, 1234\My_Documents`.

I have tried modifying a piece of script I have found on here but it changes the parent folder as well

Here is the unedited code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "StartFolder=C:\Tydelik"

cd /D %SystemRoot%
set "RenameError="

rem Rename all folders containing at least one space character in folder name.
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%StartFolder%\* *" /AD /B /S 2^>nul') do call :RenameFolder "%%I"

if defined RenameError echo/& pause
rem Restore initial environment and exit this batch file.
endlocal
goto :EOF


:RenameFolder
set "NewFolderName=%~nx1"
set "NewFolderName=%NewFolderName: =_%"

set "FolderPath=%~dp1"
if not exist "%FolderPath%" set "FolderPath=%FolderPath: =_%"
set "FullFolderName=%FolderPath%%~nx1"
if not exist "%FullFolderName%\" set "RenameError=1" & goto :EOF

for %%J in ("%FullFolderName%") do set "FolderAttributes=%%~aJ"
if "%FolderAttributes:~3,1%" == "h" %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -h "%FullFolderName%"

ren "%FullFolderName%" "%NewFolderName%" 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 goto ErrorFolderRename

if "%FolderAttributes:~3,1%" == "h" %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe +h "%FolderPath%%NewFolderName%"
goto :EOF

:ErrorFolderRename
echo Error renaming folder "%FullFolderName%"
set "RenameError=1"
if "%FolderAttributes:~3,1%" == "h" %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe +h "%FullFolderName%"
goto :EOF
```

As I said the expected output for each sub folder should be `C:\Location\John, 1234\My_Documents` instead of `C:\Location\John, 1234\My Documents`. Currently with the code I have, I get `C:\Tydelik\John,_1234\My_Documents`.

Comment: Is it always the "leaves" (the lowest subfolder, no further folders below) where you want to replace the space?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: If you're wanting to replace all spaces with underscores in all subdirectory levels below `C:\Tydelik\Name, ID"` you'll probably need to determine the lowest level branch of each and rename each as you step up a level. Imagine having `C:\Tydelik\John, 1234\My Documents\Work Files`, if your code renames `My Documents` first, i.e.  `C:\Tydelik\John, 1234\My_Documents` then the originally parsed subdirectory `C:\Tydelik\John, 1234\My Documents\Work Files` will no longer exist, _as it will be `C:\Tydelik\John, 1234\My_Documents\Work Files`_. Therefore `Work Files` may need to be processed first.

Comment: I just quickly checked and the lowest level for all folders are C:\Tydelik\John, 1234\X where is X is My Documents, Pictures, Videos etc. There are no further folders below this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what I think you're looking for, based upon the fact that you're interested only in renaming subdirectories of `"C:\Tydelik\Name, ID"`, not any contained within those subdirectories:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "SourceDir=C:\Tydelik"
For /F "EOL=?Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/AD "%SourceDir%" 2^>NUL'
)Do Set "TargetDir="&For /F "EOL=?Delims=" %%B In (
    'Dir /B/AD "%SourceDir%\%%A" 2^>NUL') Do (Set "TargetDir=%%B"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Not "!TargetDir: =!"=="!TargetDir!" (
        Ren "%SourceDir%\%%A\%%B" "!TargetDir: =_!")
    EndLocal)
```

Answer (score 1):

While Compo's solution renames folders "depth=2", this renames just the "leafes" (very last folders of a tree, "depth=last"). I kept your `call` approach to avoid delayed expansion and resulting possible problems (folder names with `!` - unlikely in your situation, but one never knows...)

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "sourcedir=..\..\"
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%sourcedir%" /ad /b /s 2^>nul') do call :RenameFolder "%%I"
goto :eof

:RenameFolder
dir /ad /b /s "%~1" 2>nul | find /v "" >nul && goto :eof  ::skip renaming, if a subfolder exists
set "leaf=%~nx1"
ECHO ren "%~1" "%leaf: =_%"
goto :eof
```

Note: for security reasons I disabled the `ren` command by just echoing it. If it works as intended, remove the `ECHO`.